# Running Total Over Multiple Years

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an Orders fact table and a connected Date dimension.

I'd like to create a running total measure by year and month, but for the current year I only want it to total up to the current date and then be blank afterwards. I'll be turning it into a bar graph and I don't want the plateau that will happen as it calculates each month that hasn't happened yet as the current YTD value.

I'm coming from a SQL background where this would be an easy task, but seems difficult in power bi/dax.

I'm currently working with the following dax:

```
SalesRT_NEW =
IF (
    MONTH ( TODAY () ) <= MAX ( DimDate[Date] ),
    TOTALYTD ( SUM ( 'FactOrderDetails(3yr)'[LineTotal] ), DimDate[Date] ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Output (as table for testing) is (starting from June for brevities sake):

```
YEAR  Month  SalesRT
2017  Jun    1500
2018  Jun    1750
2019  Jun    1900
2017  Jul    1650
2018  Jul    1858
2019  Jul    2050
2017  Aug    1800
2018  Aug    1965
2019  Aug    2050
```

Desired output:

```
YEAR  Month  SalesRT
2017  Jun    1500
2018  Jun    1750
2019  Jun    1900
2017  Jul    1650
2018  Jul    1858
2019  Jul    2050
2017  Aug    1800
2018  Aug    1965
2019  Aug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
IF(MAX(DimDate[Date]) <= today() || MONTH(MAX(DimDate[Date])) = Month(today()),TOTALYTD([SalesTotal], DimDate[Date]), BLANK())
```